# menu and header

Tags: css

Has a menu bar, and a header.
I want different menu items change the header image.

> no hover -> default header image
>
> menu1 hover -> change header image1
>
> menu2 hover -> change header image2
>
> menu3 hover -> change header image3

i create with photoshop: http://bogdany.malafree.hu/pic.jpg

Sorry for the poor english...
I'm waiting for answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the header image inside of the menu. And then you can do it like this:

```
.menu1:hover div.header1 {
       background-image:url(/header2.jpg);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery, maybe? something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // #menu is the id of either the container div or the ul
    $('#menu li').hover(
        function() {
            var index = $('#menu li').index(this);
            //#header is the ID of your header image
            $('#header').attr('src','../imgs/your_image_name'+index+'.jpg');

      },
      function() {
            $('#header').attr('src','../imgs/your_image_name.jpg');
      }
}):
```